# display date of last database field update? (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have a table of golf courses that have a "maintenance" field. 102 golf courses total.

Well, I would like to be able to display the latest date ANY of those 102 golf courses "maintenance" fields were updated.

Of course, I could create a field in the database, and manually save the date and time in there, but I wanted to see if maybe the mysql database keeps track of that ANYWAY?

Any help, thoughts, we be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What data is in the maintenance field?

Comment: I would add a `updated_at` `timestamp` field and make the field default value to update when the row is updated. Otherwise your database will not keep track of it.

Comment: i usually create a field when i am in a similar situation. it's useful and can be easily tempered manually if you need to update one without updating the timestamp.

Comment: @mikelbring Never heard of updated_at. That'll put me on the right track! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add an auto-updating `last_updated` field. However, the drawback here is that it will be updated when *any* field of that record is updated, not just the `maintenance` field.

```
CREATE TABLE `golf_courses` (
    `id`  int UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `maintenance`  text NULL ,
    `last_maintenance`  timestamp NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Another solution, of course, as you mentioned, to record the time of the last maintenance manually:

```
UPDATE
    `golf_courses` AS `g`
SET
    `g`.`maintenance` = 'new maintenance value',
    `g`.`last_maintenance` = NOW();
```